# Explanation for frequent usage of name “Abaddon”

Tags: terminology

Not sure if this is the right Stack Exchange to ask this in, but I don't think there's a "Pop Culture" Stack Exchange, so here goes:

> Why is it the case that there are so many instances in video games and pop culture in general in which a Big Bad Boss-type character is called "Abaddon"? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abaddon_in_popular_culture for examples.

I don't think I've seen any other name come up so much as a generic villain-type name. Is it:

1. Just because it's a scary name that sounds like "abandon"?
2. Some pop culture reference that's being made that I'm missing (possible, because I'm fairly young)?
3. Related to its origin in the Bible meaning Destruction?
4. A mixture of these and possibly something else?
5. Or is it something else entirely?

Any pointers you have would also be helpful, but I'd like explanations of your answers if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Questions asking why developers chose to do something are off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Hebrew term "Abaddon" (Hebrew: אֲבַדּוֹן‎ Avaddon, meaning "doom"), and its Greek equivalent "Apollyon" (Greek: Ἀπολλύων, Apollýōn) appear in the Bible as both a place of destruction and an angel of the abyss. In the Hebrew Bible, abaddon is used with reference to a bottomless pit, often appearing alongside the place שְׁאוֹל (Sheol), meaning the realm of the dead.
> -Wikipedia

---

So the name is referencing topics like "doom" or "death".

---

Comment: If more people end up downvoting this can someone tell me why?

Comment: I know the word has Biblical origin. I wasn't asking about the origin of the word. I was asking for an explanation of its frequent usage. If that it's Biblical is your response, please just say that instead of getting snarky about how I must not have done even a simple Google search. Which I did do, by the way.

Comment: @LieutenantZipp how does this not answer your question? It means "doom". That's it. A villain brings doom so obviously that makes sense. Also no one was getting snarky except debatably you

Comment: Does everyone looking for a new villain just look up the Hebrew name for "doom"? I doubt it. And you _were_ getting snarky: see your entire last paragraph. "All I had to do", "maybe do a quick check", "you don't have to do a ton of digging", "something as simple as this", "first thing to pop up when I searched it" are all instances of snark, unless your definition of the word is significantly different than mine.

Comment: "Snark" - "snide and sharply critical comments". None of my comments were critical. I used words like "simple" because this was a simple question and I wanted to make clear that I don't expect people to search the entire Internet for stuff cause im not a -hole. Also, in games whenever something is named, they are often named after Greek or Latin words (or Hebrew in this case), or ancient writings such as the Bible. I don't understand why that doesn't explain it.

Comment: I removed the part asking for a search if that makes u happy

Comment: Fine. It's enough of an answer.